# is there an equivalent of add this plugin of JQuery in GWT ?

Tags: gwt

I have an existing project that is built using GWT. We have a requirement to share the content  available on this site on majority of social sites available and JQuery addthis plugin seems to do a great job in this.

Is there a wrapper available for this to be used in GWT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy to [invoke any existing JS library](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI). As GWT programmer your horizons will broaden once you become proficient at this and it's actually very easy as I will demonstrate.

Add the jQuery and AddThis plugin source to the DOM. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/bdewong/jQuery-AddThis/master/jquery.addthis.js"/>
```

Somewhere in your application you will need to create a Anchor and assign it the class name addthis, whether you do it programically, with a uibinder template or plain old html.

```
<a class="addthis"></a>
```

Now somewhere in you application you need to invoke the addthis plugin. Here are 2 example functions you could use:

```
static native void invokeAddThis(String id) /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery(id).addthis();
}-*/;

static native void invokeAddthis(String id, String username) /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery(id).addthis(username);
}-*/;
```

Somewhere you make the call:

```
invokeAddThis(".addthis");
```

Congradulations! You can now hook into a world of existing JS API :)